# use foreach loop inside one telegram bot message

Tags: php, foreach, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a code to get the list from mysql database and sends results to a user in telegram bot. The code doesn't have any issue - but it sends a message for every result. Thats the problem and it floods the server. I tried to change the code to send all results in one message text but it sends just the last result.
main code(with out change) :

```
$sql92 = "SELECT name, price, link FROM packages";
$result92 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql92);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result92) > 0) {

    foreach($result92 as $row) {
       $packname = $row["name"];
       $packprice = $row["price"]; 
       $packlink = $row["link"];

        $amount = $packprice/100;
    $amount = $amount*80;
       $packtext = "
       $lang_packname => $packname 
       $lang_packprice => $amount $lang_sambol 
       $lang_packdesc => $packlink";
       var_dump(makereq('sendMessage',[
            'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
            'text'=>"$packtext ",
            'parse_mode'=>'MarkDown',
            'reply_markup'=>json_encode([
                'keyboard'=>[
                [
                ['text'=>"$lang_back"]
              ]
            ],
            'resize_keyboard'=>true
        ])
    ]));
    }


}
```

Comment: What result are you expecting here? You're fetching a result set from the DB. You then iterate through each result with `foreach` and are calling  `makeReq()` (which I'm guessing is sending the message?) on each iteration,.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  one message send via every results with `$packtext ` And `makeReq()` i want it send a message with all result in one message - i used `makeReq()` out of foreach but its send the one last result ~

Comment: You need to build up the payload inside the loop and then send it once outside of the loop.

Comment: Please show us your attempt at sending them all after the loop.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i just put `var_dump(makereq('sendMessage',[
            'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
            'text'=>"$packtext ",
            'parse_mode'=>'MarkDown',
            'reply_markup'=>json_encode([
                'keyboard'=>[
                [
                ['text'=>"$lang_back"]
              ]
            ],
            'resize_keyboard'=>true
        ])
    ]));` after closing the loop - i tried to use `array()` but i dont know how

Comment: You need to `concatenate` the message string inside the loop. Currently, you're overwriting it each time. Simply, put a single `.` (dot) directly before the `=`. Ex. `... $packtext .=`. This, however, will simply glue multiple strings together so the formatting of the message will likely be wrong but you should be able to make progress.

Comment: @waterloomatt thats work finaly ! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @waterloomatt

its work fine!

> You need to concatenate the message string inside the loop. Currently, you're overwriting it each time. Simply, put a single . (dot) directly before the =. Ex. ... $packtext .=. This, however, will simply glue multiple strings together so the formatting of the message will likely be wrong but you should be able to make progress.

```
$sql92 = "SELECT name, price, link FROM packages";
$result92 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql92);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result92) > 0) {

    foreach($result92 as $row) {
       $packname = $row["name"];
       $packprice = $row["price"]; 
       $packlink = $row["link"];

        $amount = $packprice/100;
    $amount = $amount*80;
       $packtext .= "
       $lang_packname => $packname 
       $lang_packprice => $amount $lang_sambol 
       $lang_packdesc => $packlink";

    }
 var_dump(makereq('sendMessage',[
            'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
            'text'=>"$packtext ",
            'parse_mode'=>'MarkDown',
            'reply_markup'=>json_encode([
                'keyboard'=>[
                [
                ['text'=>"$lang_back"]
              ]
            ],
            'resize_keyboard'=>true
        ])
    ]));

}
```